# What format is this serial data in?

Tags: python, formatting, serial-port, deserialization, pyserial

I have a Multimeter taking readings that I want to transfer directly to my PC. It has a USB port for PC connectivity and has its own software to take the readings directly, however, this software can only store a maximum of 50,000 readings per instance and requires manual saving through the software, which is inconvenient, as I'd have to write a script on top of this software to automate the saving process.

Ideally, I want to avoid using this software entirely and simply use my own script to read directly from the Multimeter, saving it straight to SQL. I am currently trying to pull the data using **pyserial**.

I wrote a very brief script to read the data from the USB:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3')
print(ser.read(200))
```

The output currently looks like this:

```
b'\xf8\xf8\x00\xf8\x80\x80x\x80\xf8\x80x\xf8x\xf8\x80x\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00x\x80\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\x00\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00\xf8\x80\x80x\x80\xf8\x80x\xf8x\xf8\x80x\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00x\x80\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\x00\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00\xf8\x80\x80x\x80\xf8\x80x\xf8x\xf8\x80x\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00x\x80\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\x00\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00\xf8\x80\x80x\x80\xf8\x80\xf8xx\xf8\x80\xf8xx\x00x\x80\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\x00\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00\xf8\x80\x80x\x80\xf8\x80x\xf8x\xf8\x80x\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00x\x80\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\x00\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00\xf8\x80\x80x\x80\xf8\x80x\xf8x\xf8\x80x\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00x\x80\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\x00\x00\xf8\x00\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00\xf8\x80\x80x\x80\xf8\x80\xf8xx\xf8\x80'
```

I have not seen data in this form before. How would I go about deserializing(?) this?

Comment: They are bytes.

Comment: @np.array How would I go about translating this into something human-readable? .decode/str.encode()?

Comment: What is the make/model of the multimeter? You might be able to find a datasheet on it. Secondly, try touching the probes together (e.g. to get 0v if measuring voltage) and note how the output changes.

Comment: You're probably looking at garbage data, i.e. you're not connected at the matching baud rate and other serial communication settings.  Very likely it's using SCPI, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Commands_for_Programmable_Instruments

Comment: @MartinEvans The product is a Digital Multimeter from Duratool, Model No. D03041. I have the physical operation manual, but it provides no meaningful information for this issue. I have checked online for a datasheet, but to no avail. Just sent an email an hour ago to Duratool to see if they've got any information handy.

Comment: I would guess to proceed you would need to scope the USB connection whilst the PC software is running. You can then see what commands it is sending and what responses it gets. There is PC software that can do this, but it will be quite technical.